# Updating text file using powershell

Tags: string, powershell, parsing

I have a folder "temp" which has a bunch of files. Each file contains text like "version:1".
I want to be able to update the version to version+1 i.e. "version:2" .

Need help to be able to do this using powershell

```
$input = Get-Content C:\temp.json
$array = @()
$input | foreach-object {
    $writeobj = $false
    $obj = New-Object System.Object
    If ($_ -match '"version"') {
        $VersionNumber = ($_ -split ':')[1]
     $VersionNumber =  $VersionNumber + 1
    }
}
```

Even though I don't see any error, I don't see the file getting updated with the new version number in this case.

Comment: Please use the search facility, _(at the top of each page)_, put together some code, run it, and if it fails to work as was written post a [mcve] of it together with example file content and the required resulting content. Until you have done that, your question is an off topic code request.

Comment: Okay, now we have some code, and a new tag/language, however, currently we have a task and some code, but no clearly defined reported issue. Can you please edit your question again, this time to explaining to us, how the code you've posted fails to achieve that task you've written it to achieve.

Comment: Please show us an example of such a json file. `"version:1"` doesn't look very json-like and is probably `"version": 1`. Also, never use `$input` as a self-defined variable, because it is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#input)

Comment: If you’re trying to modify a json file, have a read of the documentation for ```ConvertFrom-Json``` and ```ConvertTo-Json```. Your code needs to do 3 things: (i) read the file from disk and convert from json, (ii) edit the resulting  in-memory object model, (iii) Convert the modified object model back to json and save to disk.